# Set image width and height with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I upload an image with the ck editor. When i select and upload the file, the editor automatic write the image width and height.

If i dont write in to this two field manualy 100% and 100%, how can i edit this with jquery? With this code, it writes the width and height to 100%, but the ck editor add these features into style attr.

```
$('div.content img').attr('width', '100%');
$('div.content img').attr('height', '100%');
```

How can i modify the img-s style attr with jquery, and set width and height to 100%?

Thank you!

Comment: By using `css()`, but is the question how to get ckeditor to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `jQuery`'s CSS -

```
$('div.content img').css({
   'width' : '100%',
   'height' : '100%'
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: I added your code to my file. I uploaded an image, ill show you, what happend width the image. Can we somehow modify the data in the style attr?

[link](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/160725/105303771K_pkiv_g_s_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg)

Comment: @TakácsZoltán That is what that does... It seems like it is working, you set the width and height to 100%

Comment: Sorry, the editor didnt upload the edited file. :)  

It works, thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to set the style attributes, you can use jQuery's .css():

```
$('div.content img').css('width', '100%');
$('div.content img').css('height', '100%');
```

See https://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this: 
 `$("div.content img").css("cssText", "width: 100% !important;");>`  
Using jQuery to create the css and using !important to force it to take change